# Override the entity `where` clause with associated entity clause?

Tags: java, hibernate

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
@Where(clause = "deleted = 0")
public class Person

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "persion_detail_id", nullable=false)
    @Where(clause = "deleted = 1 or deleted = 0")
    private PersonDetail personDetails;

}
```

Here is PersonDetail entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "person detail")
@Where(clause = "deleted = 0 ")
public class PersonDetail  {
}
```

when personDetails is fetched I see below query gets fired

`select ...  from person_detail where id = ? and deleted =0` where  i am expecting it `select ...  from person_detail where id = ? and (deleted =0 or deleted =1)` .

Basically I want to override the entity `where` clause with associated entity `where` clause . But I found `@where` clause not working with 
`@ManyToOne` mapping at all .

I am not getting how to override  the entity `where` clause with associated entity `where` clause ?

I am using hibernate version `5.1.0`

Comment: Did you find the answer?